# callback function is not executing in exec (child_process) function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do something I think is very simple -- execute an 'echo' line using child_process.exec and then inside callback if no error then do something. My code looks as such:

```
var {exec} = require('child_process');

exec('echo "HELLO"', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(error)
    {
    }
    else
    {
      // do something
    }
});
```

It executes an 'echo' line But it's not going inside the callback function and executing that if else statement. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: How do you know the callback is not executed? I copied your code in a simple js file, ran it with node 16.3, and the callback *was* executed.

Comment: Perhaps do something inside the callback?